# gatsby setPageSection makes page jump after images finish loading

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

This current piece of code:

```
<button onClick={() =>  setPageSection([p.slug+"/", s.slug])}>
```

makes my page jump to the start of the section when the images finish loading

In this case I have a grid of pictures that are correctly lazy loaded with an initial base64 lowres pre-render but everytime each one of the pictures finishes loading the page scrolls back to the top of the section.

This only happens when I use the setPageSection.
When I click a direct link to an anchor ("page/#section") of the page instead of using the above method of setting the page section the correct behavior happens (images continue lazy loading in the background and the pages doesn't snap to the top of the section everytime when each one finishes loading).

UPDATE:
The following looks like the culprit:

```
enter useEffect(() => {
if (typeof prevPageSection === 'undefined') return;

const scrollToSection = () => {
  const el = document.getElementById(pageSection[1]);
  if (scrollContainer.current && el) {
    scrollContainer.current.scrollTo({ top: el.offsetTop });
  }
};

if (pageSection[0] !== prevPageSection![0] && pageSection[0] !== pageContext.slug) {
  navigate(locale + pageSection[0]);
  scrollContainer.current?.addEventListener('load', scrollToSection, true);
}

    scrollContainer.current?.removeEventListener('load', scrollToSection);
  }, [pageSection, prevPageSection, locale, pageContext.slug]);
```

If I remove these event listeners the page stops jumping after the images load but the links get broken (they become useless when navigating to a section on a different page, without these event listeners one can only jump to the desired section if already on that page, otherwise the browser will navigate to the top of the page)

Comment: Can you provide the full state?

Comment: sorry for my noobness but can you point me where I can learn to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have too many side effects in your `useEffect` hook. Each time one dependency (`pageSection` or `prevPageSection` or `locale` or `pageContext.slug`) is being changed, it triggers the hook, creating your unwanted effect:

```
  const el = document.getElementById(pageSection[1]);
  if (scrollContainer.current && el) {
    scrollContainer.current.scrollTo({ top: el.offsetTop });
  }
```

In addition, don't define a function inside the `useEffect` because it will cause a new scoped function creation each time the effect is triggered, overloading your code and application.

Moreover, don't point directly the DOM using `document.getElementById()`. It's a high-cost action for the browser and you can achieve the same effect using the [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) hook, you will have the exact same information using the `.current` property of the `useRef` hook, in the same way than you do the `scrollContainer.current`. Indeed, you are creating and manipulating a virtual DOM with React, to avoid pointing the DOM, while your code attacks the real DOM.

Be aware of the use of [global objects such as `window` or `document` in Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/), they are not available during the SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering) so they may potentially break your code. To summarize, `gatsby build` compiles the code in your Node server, where there is no `window` or `document` because it's not even created yet. The code may work under `gatsby develop` because it's directly rendered by the browser.

To fix your issue, I would clean the `useEffect`, you can create as many effects as needed, and you can name them using this notation to make your code more readable:

```
useEffect(someNamedFunction(){
  // your code
}, []).
```

To bypass it faster, you can create an auxiliary function that forces the page to scroll to certain element without involving the hooks:

```
const scrollToElement=(el)=>{
    scrollContainer.current.scrollTo({ top: el.offsetTop });
}

<button onClick={(el)=> scrollToElement(el)}>
```